# Confusion on expr usage

Tags: linux, bash

expr manual page says: "Pattern matches return the string matched between ( and ) or null; if ( and ) are not used, they return the number of characters matched or 0."

I am doing

```
echo `expr ABCDEF : ABC`
```

which gives 3 as expected

However, this also gives 3, why ?

```
echo `expr \( ABCDEF : ABC \)`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different kinds of parentheses there; the ones you used are part of the expression syntax, whereas your quote is about regular expression parentheses within the pattern.

```
expr \( ABCDEF : ABC \) # parenthesized expression
expr ABCDEF : \(ABC\) # capturing parentheses in pattern
```

Comment: But your second example still does not return the string matched. It still returns the number of characters matched.

Comment: Hm, you dropped `` \ ``s and I didn't doublecheck. `expr abcdef : '\(abc\)' ` works.

Comment: yes I was applying single quotes incorrectly. It was as per your latest example above. Thanks.